# Where should I ask for recommendations based on a given artist or song?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if a stack exchange website even exists for this, but I'm looking for a recommendation based on an artist, album, or song. Is it appropriate to ask for something like this on music.stackexchange? Unfortunately, I can't think of a place to ask this kind of question on the internet, and I just can't seem to find an answer to my question by simply googling around.

Answer (score 3):

There's [an Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17796/music) that looks to cover recommendations.  You'll note that they're explicitly mentioned as off-topic in [our FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/faq), and though it could change I really don't see it happening.  The ones we've gotten (and closed) have all been terrible.

Comment: Committed! When I want to ask a question, I want to StackExchange it :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Raskolnikov's list of sites which provide recommendations, last.fm, iTunes and others provide this as a service.

It is an area very well served currently, but that has almost no applicability to the Stack Exchange model. All recommendations on music are subjective, by their very nature. Stack Exchange aims to be entirely objective, providing the correct answer to the question.

I don't think there is any way to build this into the SE model.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a lot of discussion boards where you can ask this kind of questions. A quick Google search gives this:

http://www.music-discussion.com/forum/forum.php

http://musicboards.com/

http://www.muzicforums.com/

Seriously, if you say you didn't find an answer by Googling around, you didn't Google around well.

Nevertheless, I am a proponent of opening the scope of this stackexchange and allow this type of questions, provided they are community type questions. I think this would also increase activity on the site.