# Should we explicitly include “piece recommendations” as a close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Our [Help Center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that asking for recommendations of pieces of music is off-topic:

> If you have a question […] [that] is not about…
>
> - recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria
>
> […] … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

But, when voting to close a question the closest *close reason* is probably:

> - **Recommendations for specific hardware, software, apps, equipment, brands, or the like are off-topic**
>   This question asks for a product recommendation of either hardware, software, app, equipment brands/models, etc. If the question relates to general usage of hardware, equipment, or software please help the user edit to make it more clear.

… and this doesn’t mention recommendations for *pieces of music*.

---

I suggest that either “recommendations of pieces of music” be added the the above close reason, or perhaps that a new close reason be added.  What does everyone think about this idea?

Is there anything else about the recommendations close reason that should be updated?

#### Related

- [Updating close reasons to fit the new format](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/updating-close-reasons-to-fit-the-new-format)
- [What criteria should we use when choosing close reasons for marginal questions?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/what-criteria-should-we-use-when-choosing-close-reasons-for-marginal-questions)
- [Where should I ask for recommendations based on a given artist or song?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/where-should-i-ask-for-recommendations-based-on-a-given-artist-or-song)

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation for specific things are often opinion based. They may also lead to "open list" answers, both being incompatible with the SE format.

So in principal, the "community-specific: recommendations..." reason is redundant. It however helps to clarify that the common types of questions are off-topic. In case of recommendations for commercial products it also clarifies that spam and advertising are uninvited.

I would agree, adding recommendations for repertoire and educational materials to this list would make sense. While recommendations for repertoire may not always be spam, it is still opinion based and an open list.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and suggest changing the transcribing/finding close reason to:

> Questions about **transcribing, finding, or recommending** a particular song, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.

Comment: This doesn't belong here. A recommendation for repertoire might very well be useful for future readers, and the reasons why we don't want such recommendations are different (opinion based, and potential for spam/advertising).

Comment: @user1079505 The help center clarifies that recommendations for rep are off-topic. If you think they should be on-topic, that's a separate meta question to bring that up for discussion and potentially changing the help center. As recommendations for rep are currently off topic, this meta question is about whether and how do we clarify that they are off topic in close reasons. Or maybe I don't understand your comment?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree that the recommendations for repertoire should remain off-topic. I'm arguing however that they don't fit the justification mentioned by Aaron.